# Get data from database and sort it by date and then by user in HTML table

Tags: php

I have some records that i want to sort by date and then by user on server side or client side.

Here is my code.

```
    if (isset($_POST['work_report']) && $_POST['work_report'] == 'SAVE') {
        $from_date = $_POST['from_date'];
        $to_date   = $_POST['to_date'];
        $users      = isset($_POST['users']) ? $_POST['users'] : array();
        if (empty($users)) {
            header("location: work_dairy_report");
        } else {
            $reports = array();
            foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
                if ($user == 0) {
                    $work_report = "SELECT * FROM " . WORK_REPORT_TABLE . " WHERE work_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'";
                } else {
                    $work_report = "SELECT * FROM " . WORK_REPORT_TABLE . " WHERE work_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' AND staff_id = $user";
                }
                $result_work_report = $db->execute_query($work_report);
                while ($report = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_work_report)) {
                    $reports[] = $report;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Why not directly use the `ORDER BY` clause in your query?

Comment: short in the query not after the data is generated. use `SELECT column1, column2,...
FROM table
ORDER BY column1 [ASC|DESC], column2 [ASC|DESC],...`

Comment: It looks like some of the tags have nothing to do with the "question" ..? Btw. what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the easiest option is to add `ORDER BY work_date, staff_id` to SELECT statements like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . WORK_REPORT_TABLE . " WHERE work_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' ORDER BY work_date";

"SELECT * FROM " . WORK_REPORT_TABLE . " WHERE work_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' AND staff_id = $user ORDER BY work_date, staff_id";
```

More info on `ORDER BY` usage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)